# IFrame on Classic ASP page, all other content being hidden somehow

Tags: iframe, asp-classic

I have an already existing asp page that I would like to add an IFrame to. The problem is wherever I add the frame in the Body, everything past that point no longer displays. If I take a table that is already there and copy it a second time I see the table twice on the screen, but if I take the contents of the second table and replace them with an IFrame then everything else on my page below that point goes invisible. Anybody have an idea what might be causing this behavior?

```
</HEAD>
    <body style="font-size:12">
        <form>
 <table  width=50% align=center >
 <tr><td  align=center >

 <font  style="font-size:12px;BackGround-Color:yellow"> Your test results were successfully
mailed to <%=Request("MailTo") %></font>


 </td></tr></table>
 <%End IF %>

 <br />

 <table align=center><tr><td colspan="10"><input id="Button3" onclick="return ConfirmExit(<%=intTestRecordID%>)"
                            value="Go to Locker" type="button" name="btnButton"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <input id="Button4" onclick="javascript:window.print()" value="Print Summary Report" type="button"
                            name="btnPrint">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="btnGoToEmail" onclick="javascript:document.location='#EmailReport'"
                        value="Email Report" type="button" name="btnButton"></td> </tr><br />



 </table>
    <br />

    <%=BuildReport(objTest,false) %>    

    <br />

<table align=center><tr><td colspan="10"><input id="Button1" onclick="return ConfirmExit(<%=tstID%>)"
                            value="Go to Locker" type="button" name="btnButton"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="Button2" onclick="javascript:window.print()" value="Print Summary Report" type="button"
name="btnPrint"></td></tr></table>



        </form>
        <br />
        <a name="EmailReport"></a>
            <form method="POST" name="emailtestresults" action='?emailedresults=1&TestRecordID=<%=Request.querystring("TestRecordID")%>'>


    <table  style='BORDER-BOTTOM:lightgrey thin solid; BORDER-LEFT:lightgrey thin solid; font-size:12px; MARGIN:0px; BORDER-TOP:lightgrey thin solid; BORDER-RIGHT:lightgrey thin solid' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='4' width='55%' align='center'>
    <tr><td  >
    <B><%=ReplaceResourceDefault(GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults1"),muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)%></B>
    </td></tr>
    <!--ANP WR1309
    Send a copy of your <%'=lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)%> results to yourself, your boss, your spouse, or anyone you
    want to impress...<p>
    To email your <%'=lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)%> results, enter the email address
    and a brief message you want attached to the top of your <%'=lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)%> results and click the OK button.
    -->
    <tr><td>
    <%=ReplaceResourceCustom(GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults2"),"%%ZZ%%",lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT))%> 
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>

    <b>Send Results to:</b><input type="text" size="30" name="mailto" value="<%=Session("EmailAddress")%>">

    </td></tr>
    <!-- ANP WR1309
    <strong>Message to Include with <%'=muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT%> Results:</strong><br>
    -->
    <tr><td>
<B><% Response.write ReplaceResourceDefault(GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults4"),muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT) %>
</B><br />
    <textarea rows="8" name="Message" cols="55"></textarea>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <%'ANP WR1309
    'DisplayComplexFormBtn "javascript:document.emailtestresults.submit();", "Email your " & lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT) & " results", "Email your " & lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT) & " results", 0, 0, "", "Email Results"
    DisplayComplexFormBtn "javascript:document.emailtestresults.submit();", ReplaceResourceCustom(GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults5"),"%%ZZ%%",lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)), ReplaceResourceCustom(GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults5"),"%%ZZ%%",lcase(muREPLACE_TEST_TEXT)), 0, 0, "", GetResourceText("ScoreReportASP_msgCustomEmailResults6")    

    %>
    </td></tr>
    </table>


    </form>
    </body>
</HTML>

<script  language="javascript">
    function ConfirmExit(TestRecordId) {
        var blnOK = confirm("Please make sure you have printed or emailed your results before returning to the Learning Locker. Once you have left this page you will not be able to return.");
        if (blnOK == true) {

        window.location.href = "/lockerweb/mylocker.aspx?cptrid=" + TestRecordId; 
            return true;
        }

    }

</script>
```

If I add this iFrame

```
            <iframe src="http://www.amazon.com" frameborder="No" width="100%" height="200" id="iFrame" vspace="10">
```

anywhere on the page, then the rest of the page's below the iframe will disappear. If I check the source all of the code is there, just not visible.

Comment: You don't add iFrame to the page that you want to display in the iFrame. You add an iFrame on another page where you want to include the included page. You seems to have misunderstood the iFrame. iFrame itself doesn't have any HTML, it only loads an external Url.

Comment: True. Show your HTML so we can show you an edited version.

Comment: I understand how iFrames work, I am attempting to load an external Url within my page. I add the iFrame pointing to http://www.bestbuy.com (example) and then everything below the iFrame on my page disappears.

Comment: If I take the 2nd table and copy it right below itself, then the table will display twice. If I then remove the contents of the table and replace with the iframe everything disappears. Can you explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your Iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.amazon.com" frameborder="No" width="100%" height="200" id="iFrame" vspace="10"></iframe>
```

Comment: Agreed - I do not see a close </iframe> tag following the open tag.

Comment: I agree as well - I am the biggest idiot in the room, by far.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a set of fresh eyeballs. :)